# How to "Trim" a maskedTextbox. C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a maskedTextbox from a wpftoolkit from this [link](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Documentation)

I have 2 problems:

1. When I click in the masked textbox it will place the curser in say the 4th space. (This is a maxlength of 6) and in the debugger it will show the `maskedTextbox.text = ___4__. 
   I only want the`4`not the other`_`. I tried trimming it and toString and nothing seems to work. I also could not find a property that will basically move everything to the left if it has a space.
2. when i click on the textbox i wasnt the cursor to automatically align to the left. I tried adding an event `MouseLeftButtonDown="maskedText_MouseLeftButtonDown"` and in that event `selectionStart = 0`; but that too, did not work.

   ```
   <Xceed:MaskedTextBox x:Name="maskedTextDuration" Mask="000000"  MaxLength="6" 
   Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="3" TextChanged="maskedTextDuration_TextChanged"
   MouseLeftButtonDown="maskedTextDuration_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There was a builtIn Property called PromptChar and I used that to set it to PromptChar=" " That allowed me to get maskedTextbox.text = "   4  " then using Trim I could just get 4.

Comment: Good find that did take the place of the Trim(). Thanks.